# Unable get Facebook User_birthday, Location in Swift2

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

Below is my code :-

```
let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile","user_birthday","email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in

    if (error == nil)
    {
        let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result

        if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
        {
            self.getFBUserData()     
        }
    }
})
}

func getFBUserData()
{

    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil)
    {
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture, email, gender, age_range, birthday"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil)
            {
                print(result)
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login_with_facebook_vc", sender: nil) 
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I am new in swift2. So i am unable to get facebook `user_birthday`, `location`.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to get email:

```
func getEmail() {

    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email"])
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            print("fetched user: \(result)")
            if let facebookEmail: String = result.valueForKey("email") as? String {

                print("email is: \(facebookEmail)")
                self.email = facebookEmail

            }
        }
    })

}
```

Try this with birthday